# Facebook javascript API - adding page/tab

Tags: javascript, facebook

Trying to get the installation of my Facebook Canvas app working. What I need to do is let the use choose a page on which to install the app. I am getting a list of pages via the API, putting them in a select box to choose from, which works fine:

```
FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response){
    for (var i=0 ; i<response.data.length ; i++)
    {
        // now build a DOM node to allow selection of this page
        var option_node = $("<option value='" + 
                             response.data[i].id + 
                             "'>" + 
                             response.data[i].name + "</option>");
        $('#facebook_page_list').append(option_node);
    }
});
```

Selecting the option gets to the right place, where I use the page Id and access token to attach a page tab for my app:

```
    var api_call = '/' + page_id + '/tabs/';
        FB.api(api_call, 
               'post', 
               {
                 page_id:     page_id,
                 tab:         'app_' + appId,
                 access_token: page_access_token,
                 custom_name: 'Joe Agent'
               }, 
               function(response){
                      console.log("Did this work?");
                      console.log(response);
              });
```

but I get an error message:
     Tab 'app_' does not exist on profile

Why does the "add this tab to this page" call return the error "that tab doesn't exist on that page"? What am I missing here?

THanks,
andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I needed to do more setup on my page in order to do this. going by this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs, I got past this issue. In case this trips someone else up.